# Python conditional loop evaluating backwards

Tags: python, python-3.x

So I've got this loop I'm working on, and it is supposed to check `n` number of csv files, look for "TD" in cell A1, and if it doesn't find it move the file to the `badPath`. But the it evaluates exactly backwards, meaning that files with "TD" get dumped into the `badPath`. This is my 'working' code. With the `shutil.move(os.path.join(path,f),badPath)` call outside of the `with loop` the code executes, only it identifies files with this identifier as not having it.

```
data = []

for f in TD_files:    
    with open(f, newline='', encoding='utf-8') as g: 
        r = csv.reader((line.replace('\0', '') for line in g))
        data = [line for line in r] 
        if data[0] != 'TD': 
            print('Not A Trend File') 
    shutil.move(os.path.join(path,f),badPath)
```

**Code I have tried which hasn't worked:**

```
data = []

for f in TD_files:    
    with open(f, newline='', encoding='utf-8') as g: 
        r = csv.reader((line.replace('\0', '') for line in g))
        data = [line for line in r] 
        if data[0] != 'TD': 
            print('Not A Trend File') 
            shutil.move(os.path.join(path,f),badPath)
```

This produces a `PermissionError` because the processes are all tied up in one another. I have included an image of the error and called it error1.

```
data = []

for f in TD_files:    
    with open(f, newline='', encoding='utf-8') as g: 
        r = csv.reader((line.replace('\0', '') for line in g))
        data = [line for line in r if data[0] != 'TD']  
        print('Not A Trend File')
        shutil.move(os.path.join(path,f),badPath)
```

This code was my first inclination and it produces an `IndexError: list out of range` which leads me to assume that my evaluations are incorrect.

**Question**

Am I having syntactical errors, logical errors with my understanding of the python language and its general logic and rules, or is there something simple here I'm missing? I am running my tests on a batch on 127 files, each range from 10,000 to 50,000 rows & 26 to 50 columns. But they each have 'TD' in cell A1, so this leads me to assume I'm having a logical misunderstanding here, because each and every file is being moved to the `badPath`.

[error1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q6W4P.png)

Comment: "But the it evaluates exactly backwards, meaning that files with "TD" get dumped into the badPath." No, it doesn't; it moves **every** file, because there is no part of the code that restricts `shutil.move(os.path.join(path,f),badPath)` from happening. "Code I have tried which hasn't worked:" This is the correct logic; the `shutil.move` needs to be inside the `if`, because that's **the rule that tells you** whether to move the file. "This produces a PermissionError because the processes are all tied up in one another." Right; you need to do this test **after** the file is closed.

Comment: "Am I having syntactical errors, logical errors with my understanding of the python language and its general logic and rules, or is there something simple here I'm missing?" You are having logical errors. If there were syntactical errors, Python would raise a `SyntaxError`. That's what it's for.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of errors or program output when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) Instead, copy and paste terminal output, formatted like code. We [will not transcribe](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/415040) images for you.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Your answer was exactly the logic I was looking for. Thank you for helping me think through this. I come from C#, C++, JS, SQL, and DAX. Thinking in Python is still new to me as I've only been 6 to 8 months. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> This produces a PermissionError because the processes are all tied up in one another.

We cannot move the file until it is closed; and it is open for the duration of the `with` block. However, `with` **does not create a new scope** in Python (very few things do), so we can easily compute values and then use them afterwards.

Rather than read the entire file in order to use indexing to get the first line, we can just read the first line out of the `csv.reader`, check whether the file is "bad", and set a flag to use afterwards:

```
for f in TD_files:    
    with open(f, newline='', encoding='utf-8') as g: 
        r = csv.reader((line.replace('\0', '') for line in g))
        is_trend = next(r)[0] == 'TD'
    if not is_trend:
        print('Not A Trend File')
        shutil.move(os.path.join(path, f), badPath)
```

(For that matter, we can probably just check whether the actual *text of* the file starts with `TD`, rather than parsing it as a CSV...)

Comment: Out of curiosity, how would we check the _actual text of the file_ rather than parsing it out through the csv reader. I thought that what the csv reader was doing for us?...

Comment: Every file... is a file. The CSV format is a kind of plain text format, which is why we open the file in a text mode. Rather than using `csv.reader`, we could directly `.read` a bit from the file.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are closest in your second snippet of code because the `move()` is inside the `if`. However, the `if` is inside the `open()` context. You just need to move the `if` outside the context:

```py
data = []

for f in TD_files:    
    with open(f, newline='', encoding='utf-8') as g: 
        r = csv.reader((line.replace('\0', '') for line in g))
        data = [line for line in r] 
        # data now has file contents having exhausted g

    # outside the context, the file is closed
    if data[0] != 'TD': 
        print('Not A Trend File') 
        shutil.move(os.path.join(path,f),badPath)
```